# How to get the picturebox image path that captured by the webcam

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

In my form. I have two picturebox and a button that capture the image into picturebox.

Two Picturebox

- WebcamImage - represent the live camera image
- PreviewImage - represent the Captured image from webcamimage

When i saved this captured image it will go to my UserImage picturebox (In my Usercontrol)

The problems is i don't know how i'm gonna get the picturebox image path.
 What i want is when i click my saved button the image path will be saved to my label text.

Here's my code

PS: I'm using Aforge.dll

```
public partial class CaptureImage : Form
{
    private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;
    RegisterCustomer _view;
    public CaptureImage(RegisterCustomer view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._view = view;
    }
    private void CaptureImage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        if (FinalFrame.VideoCapabilities.Length > 0)
        {
            string highestSolution = "0;0";
            //Search for the highest resolution
            for (int i = 0; i < FinalFrame.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
            {
                if (FinalFrame.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width > Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[0]))
                    highestSolution = FinalFrame.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width.ToString() + ";" + i.ToString();
            }
        }
        FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
        FinalFrame.Start();
        btn_save.Hide();
        btn_cancel.Hide();
    }
    void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        WebcamImage.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
    private void CaptureImage_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
        {
            FinalFrame.Stop();
        }
    }
    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.UserImage.Image = PreviewImage.Image;
        this.Close();
    }
    private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    private void btn_capture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        PreviewImage.Image = (Bitmap)WebcamImage.Image.Clone();
        PreviewImage.BringToFront();          
        btn_capture.Hide();
        btn_save.Show();
        btn_cancel.Show();
    }
}
```

This is only i know in getting the picturebox image path by using openfile dialog

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;.*.png; | *.jpg;*.jpeg;.*.png;)";
            ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
            ofd.Title = "Select Image File";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                location = ofd.FileName;
                path.Text = location;
                UserImage.Image = Image.FromFile(location);
                UserImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;             
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the image to file [Image.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria can you elaborate it more, don't understand what your trying to explain

Comment: You're not saving the Bitmap anywhere. You're passing it to a PictureBox(?) of the `RegisterCustomer` (Form? UserControl? CustomControl?). If `RegisterCustomer.UserImage` is a PictureBox control, you can save the Bitmap using the internal Save method: `RegisterCustomer.UserImage.Image.Save([Path], ImageFormat.Png)`. To create a PNG, that is.

Comment: @Diether What I've understood is that you want to show the path, where you previously saved an image, in a label, but I don't see that you ever have saved your image.

Comment: @Jimi Your right. Thanks. I will try this